# Visual Studio still creating .bsc files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to disable creating .bsc files in my work project. But I really don't understand how to do it!! Before I begin Visual Studio was creating 200mb of .bsc files for my project. After disabling in

- Project properties
- C/C++
- Browse Information (Enable Browse Information: **No**)

  count of files and all size was decreased to 100mb.

Then I set Preserve SBR Files to **No**. And open all vcxproj files in notepad and replace all tags `<BrowseInformation>true</BrowseInformation>` to **false**. After building there still some .bsc files with total size 50mb.
How I can defeat this files?!)